# How to merge in row items to groups by using underscores?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js

I have a list of objects:

```
var list = [
   {owner_email: "maxim", value: "v1"},
   {owner_email: "maxim", value: "v2"},
   {owner_email: "vlad", value: "v3"},
   {owner_email: "maxim", value: "v4"},
   {owner_email: "bob", value: "v5"},
   {owner_email: "bob", value: "v6"},
   {owner_email: "bob", value: "v7"},
   {owner_email: "vlad", value: "v8"},
   {owner_email: "maxim", value: "v9"},
   {owner_email: "maxim", value: "v10"},
   {owner_email: "bob", value: "v11"}
   ];
```

I want to use `underscores` to merge in row items to groups.

So the output should look like:

```
output: [
{owner_email: "maxim", values: ["v1", "v2"]},
{owner_email: "vlad", values: ["v3"]},
{owner_email: "maxim", values: ["v4"]},
{owner_email: "bob", values: ["v5", "v6", "v7"]},
{owner_email: "vlad", values: ["v8"]},
{owner_email: "maxim", values: ["v9", "v10"]},
{owner_email: "bob", values: ["v11"]}
]
```

As you can see, for example, in `list` 1st two items email refer to `maxim` therefore I group 1st and second lines to: `{owner_email: "maxim", values: ["v1", "v2"]},`.

How to make it work?

This what i wrote so far:

```
$scope.result = [];

     for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++){
       if(i === 0){
         $scope.result.push({
             owner_email: list[i].owner_email,
             values: [list[i].value]
         });
       }
       else{

       var item = list[i];
       var oldItem = _.findWhere($scope.result, {owner_email:item.owner_email});
       if(!oldItem ){
        $scope.result.push({
             owner_email: item.owner_email,
             values: [item.value]
         });
       }
       else{
       console.log(oldItem);

       angular.forEach($scope.result, function(_r){
           if(_r.owner_email === oldItem.owner_email){
              _r.values.push(item.value);
           }
           else{
           row = false;
           }
        });
       }
     }// for
```

[This is a demo I play with](http://jsfiddle.net/m0p1nbvj/)

Comment: Just iterate over the array and append to the previous / last value if the `owner_email` values are the same? Don't think underscore provides any helper method specific to this.

Comment: its not so easy as it looks like, increment list during iteration ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that just iterates over the list and keeps track of the current item:

```
var output = [];
var current = { owner_email: null };

_.each( list, function(item){
    if( item.owner_email != current.owner_email){
        current = { owner_email : item.owner_email, values: [item.value]};
        output.push(current);
    }
    else {
        current.values.push(item.value);
    }
});
```